# Implement SeparableConv2D in Pytorch

Tags: python, tensorflow, pytorch, conv-neural-network, convolution

### Main objective

PyTorch equivalent for SeparableConv2D with `padding = 'same'`:

```py
from tensorflow.keras.layers import SeparableConv2D
x = SeparableConv2D(64, (1, 16), use_bias = False, padding = 'same')(x)
```

### What is the PyTorch equivalent for SeparableConv2D?

This [source](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/depthwise-and-separable-convolutions-in-pytorch/7315) says:

> If groups = nInputPlane, kernel=(K, 1), (and before is a Conv2d layer with groups=1 and kernel=(1, K)), then it is separable.

While this [source](https://www.programmersought.com/article/1344745736/) says:

> Its core idea is to break down a complete convolutional acid into a two-step calculation, Depthwise Convolution and Pointwise.

This is my attempt:

```py
class SeparableConv2d(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, in_channels, out_channels, depth, kernel_size, bias=False):
        super(SeparableConv2d, self).__init__()
        self.depthwise = nn.Conv2d(in_channels, out_channels*depth, kernel_size=kernel_size, groups=in_channels, bias=bias)
        self.pointwise = nn.Conv2d(out_channels*depth, out_channels, kernel_size=1, bias=bias)

    def forward(self, x):
        out = self.depthwise(x)
        out = self.pointwise(out)
        return out
```

Is this correct? Is this equivalent to `tensorflow.keras.layers.SeparableConv2D`?

### What about `padding = 'same'`?

How to ensure that my input and output size is the same while doing this?

My attempt:

```
x = F.pad(x, (8, 7, 0, 0), )
```

Because the kernel size is `(1,16)`, I added left and right padding, 8 and 7 respectively. Is this the right way (and best way) to achieve `padding = 'same'`? How can I place this inside my `SeparableConv2d` class, and calculate on the fly given the input data dimension size?

### All together

```py
class SeparableConv2d(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, in_channels, out_channels, depth, kernel_size, bias=False):
        super(SeparableConv2d, self).__init__()
        self.depthwise = nn.Conv2d(in_channels, out_channels*depth, kernel_size=kernel_size, groups=in_channels, bias=bias)
        self.pointwise = nn.Conv2d(out_channels*depth, out_channels, kernel_size=1, bias=bias)

    def forward(self, x):
        out = self.depthwise(x)
        out = self.pointwise(out)
        return out


class Net(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Net, self).__init__()
        self.separable_conv = SeparableConv2d(
            in_channels=32, 
            out_channels=64, 
            depth=1, 
            kernel_size=(1,16)
        )
        
    def forward(self, x):
        x = F.pad(x, (8, 7, 0, 0), )
        x = self.separable_conv(x)
        return x
```

Any problem with these codes?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The linked definitions are generally agreeing. The best one is in the [article](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1706.03059.pdf).

- "Depthwise" (not a very intuitive name since depth is not involved) - is a series of regular 2d convolutions, just applied to layers of the data separately. - "Pointwise" is same as `Conv2d` with 1x1 kernel.

I suggest a few correction to your `SeparableConv2d` class:

- no need to use depth parameter - it is same as out_channels
- I set padding to 1 to ensure same output size with `kernel=(3,3)`. if kernel size is different - adjust padding accordingly, using same principles as with regular Conv2d. Your example class `Net()` is no longer needed - padding is done in `SeparableConv2d`.

This is the updated code, should be similar to `tf.keras.layers.SeparableConv2D` implementation:

```
class SeparableConv2d(nn.Module):

def __init__(self, in_channels, out_channels, kernel_size, bias=False):
    super(SeparableConv2d, self).__init__()
    self.depthwise = nn.Conv2d(in_channels, in_channels, kernel_size=kernel_size, 
                               groups=in_channels, bias=bias, padding=1)
    self.pointwise = nn.Conv2d(in_channels, out_channels, 
                               kernel_size=1, bias=bias)

def forward(self, x):
    out = self.depthwise(x)
    out = self.pointwise(out)
    return out
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I have questions on the `self.depthwise` layer. Why is it `nn.Conv2d(1,1)` and not nn.Conv2d(in_channels, in_channels)`. And why is the `groups` parameter not used but instead performs `x. reshape` first followed by Conv2d with 1 filter?

Comment: My example was based on assumption that all layers are convolved depthwise with same filter. After reviewing `tf.keras.layers.SeparableConv2D` implementation, I see that TF uses different filters for each layer. You are correctly suggesting that it will be `nn.Conv2d(in_channels=N, out_channels=N, groups=N)  # N is in_channels`. I will update the example in my solution with both options.

Comment: What is `torch_s2d` (I'm having `name 'torch_s2d' is not defined ` here)? And what is `self.depthwise.weight[1:] = torch_s2d.depthwise.weight[0]` doing, initial weights?

Comment: `torch_s2d` is a leftover from testing. I removed it from the answer and also removed the second case - just left one that should match the TF implementation as you asked.